# Can you access private variables using OGNL?

Tags: java, reflection, ognl, private-members

Is there anyway using [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/) to access private variables that aren't exposed as a bean property (ie no `get`/`set` method pair)? I wanted to use OGNL as a faster, cleaner method of reflection for use in unit tests.

Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void shouldSetup() throws OgnlException{
    class A{
        private Object b = "foo";
        private Object c = "bar";
        public Object getB(){ return b; }
    }
    A a = new A();

    System.out.println( "This'll work..." );
    Ognl.getValue( "b", a );

    System.out.println( "...and this'll fail..." );
    Ognl.getValue( "c", a );

    System.out.println( "...and we'll never get here." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can. You need to set `MemberAccess` in `OgnlContext` to allow access to non public fields and use `getValue(ExpressionAccessor expression, OgnlContext context, Object root)` method to retrieve value.

```java
@Test
public void shouldSetup() throws OgnlException {
    class A {
        private Object b = "foo";
        private Object c = "bar";
        public Object getB() { return b; }
    }
    A a = new A();

    // set DefaultMemberAccess with allowed access into the context
    OgnlContext context = new OgnlContext();
    context.setMemberAccess(new DefaultMemberAccess(true));

    System.out.println( "This'll work..." );
    // use context in getValue method
    Ognl.getValue( "b", context, a );

    System.out.println( "...and this'll work..." );
    // use context in getValue method
    Ognl.getValue( "c", context, a );

    System.out.println( "...and we'll get here." );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do was a work around using reflection directly:

```
static Object getValue( final String ognlPath, final Object o ){
    final StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( ognlPath, "." );

    Object currentO = o;
    String nextFieldName = null;
    try{
        while( st.hasMoreTokens() ){
            nextFieldName = st.nextToken();

            if( currentO == null ){
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Cannot find field '" + nextFieldName + "' on null object." );
            }

            Field f = currentO.getClass().getDeclaredField( nextFieldName );
            f.setAccessible( true );
            currentO = f.get( currentO );
        }

        return currentO;

    }catch( NoSuchFieldException e ){
        throw new RuntimeException( "Could not find field '" + nextFieldName + "' on " + currentO.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e );

    }catch( IllegalAccessException e ){
        throw new RuntimeException( "Failed to get from path '" + ognlPath + "' on object: " + o, e );
    }
}
```